# How to know if tomcat is running (and its port number) on my windows machine?

Tags: c#

I am running a c# application and I need to know whether Apache Tomcat is running or not and also know the port for it.

There are multiple ways Tomcat is installed. In certain installations, I get the service in the Services list while in some I do not.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like Process.GetProcesses from System.Diagnostics;

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

and check for the relevant process name in that list. Otherwise look at some answers [of the related links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262291/685760) to find a specific process name (ie. Tomcat).

For finding the port, this might be a little harder programatically. You might have to parse Tomcat's configuration file $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml to find the ports in use. You'd be looking for something like;

```
<Connector port="{portNumber is here}"...
```

Take a look at the Tomcat documentation regarding the configuration files.

Comment: The process name is not "Tomcat", but it is "Java" and the attribute "MainWindowName" is "Tomcat". I am using a combination of getting the services and processes to know whether Tomcat is running or not and reading the port from the config file. But I wanted to do it without reading the config.

Comment: You could use PortReporter - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9964 as an alternative to scanning the config files.