# Hold the process until application doesn't get closed

Tags: c#, process

I know there are lot of post about to hold process until application doesn't get closed.

Actually what I want to do is that when I load the word file in MS Word using `Process.Start()` method the application should hold the process until it doesn't get closed. After closing this word file I am also updating it in database. So for that I was using `Process.WaitForExit()` method. But, this method doesn't work in some machine. So, I have read about this problem in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx) they have suggested me to use `Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` property to `true`. But, it throws error even the [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username(v=vs.110).aspx) property is assined. So I have decided to create my own method to hold the process.

```
foreach (Process c in Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD"))
{
    while (c.MainWindowTitle.Contains("MyDOC NAME") && c.HasExited == false)
    {} //this loop will hold the process until Word application doesn't get exited.
}
```

But, this method also not working. Any property of `Process` class object doesn't have any value. `c.MainWindowTitle` shows blank, `c.HasExited` throws exception.

Now I am stuck here. Neither I can use `Process.WaitForExit()` nor above method. I have also another option [WMI Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146(VS.80).aspx) to return current process as solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270286/3761928). But, i don't think that this method will for in this case. **When my OS is not using ShellExecute.**

I just want to hold the process until application doesn't get closed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please add debugging steps you have taken and EXACTLY the issues you have had with each approach you have tried.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is occurred in client's machine not in my PC. So, I could not debug it. I have tested that by creating log entry on every step and I have determine that `c.MainWindowTitle` property does not hold the Document Title in it. It showing blank. I have faced this problem also about a year ago in another PC where VS is installed. The object of Process was not holding values of its any property as I have mentioned in my question *c.MainWindowTitle shows blank, c.HasExited throws exception.*

Comment: have you asked for OS Version? .Net Version? Have you tried on your computer with debugging? Do they have a "Debug" or "Release" version?

Comment: Actually my application is built for .Net 2.0 with 32bit OS (Windows XP) and Client is having both type of machine Windows XP (32bit) and Windows 8 (64bit) and the problem occurred in on 64bit PC. But, I have also tested it on Windows 7(64bit) where  VS is installed. In that Windows 7 PC its working.

Comment: have you looked at the API changes from Windows 7 to Windows 8? Are you aware that EOL for .Net 2.0 happened in 2010? http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework