# C# - Process.GetProcesses() not returning user processes when Executed in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, monitoring

I am trying to create a Service that regularly collects data about the running applications/processes on a computer. The Process.GetProcesses() function works and returns the processes when I am running the service in Visual Studio or by simply running the executable  but it does not identify the user specific applications when running as a window services. I have already set the Windows Service to interact with the desktop but it still returns empty.

The service already has elevated privileges and is being run as Local System.
Is there any way of getting the user specific applications when running under a window services

Comment: The Processes of which user? There might be none or multiple.

Comment: The users who are logged in to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trough WMI? It probably also matters which permissions the account has, on which your service is running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--processes

[how to get all the users processes in WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269677/how-to-get-all-the-users-processes-in-wmi)