# "Name 'Process' does not exist in current context" error in console app

Tags: c#, process, compiler-errors, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to use the `Process` class but it gives me this compiler error every time I do

> The name 'Process' does not exist in the current context

I've already added `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top of my code but I still get this error. Autocomplete wont even recognize the class.

Hear is the code. I've only included the `Main method` because the rest of the code has nothing to do with the error.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AIRuntime adam = new AIRuntime("Adam", false);
        adam.AIUpdate();
        Process.Start(adam.directory);  //adam.directory is just a string
    }
}
```

My IDE is Xamarin Studio if it matters.

Comment: Yes. Just accidentally did not include in above code.   .Fixed it

Comment: I believe you when you say the rest of your code has nothing to do with your error, but excluding it makes it impossible for us to try to reproduce it. Can you reproduce the error without the references to your custom classes? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @BradleyDotNET System.Diagnostics.Process is in the core, there is no reference to add.

Comment: Does not repro for me - I added your code to a new project and it works fine (and you don't need any usings except `System.Diagnostics`).

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I couldn't remember, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yeah i had to go look it up myself :)

Comment: people.. he did not invent the words "The name 'Process' dose not exist in the current context" - of course it works for you - but why isn't it working for him?.. that is the question here...

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the error from your "adam" process after it is being executed by the process.start?

Comment: @G.Y he did invent the word "dose" however, which means that the error message was not a straight copy paste :)

Comment: @DavidL and perhaps his clipboard is being messed by Adam Process  :) either way - we need more info.

Comment: What is the executable being started here?  Is it executing itself by any chance, or is it also a .Net program that relies on the process class?  Because it itself could be crashing with that error and Visual Studio is catching the output from it and dumping it to your output window misleading you into thinking it's coming from the code you are building above.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a compiler error. The IDE wont let me run the program because of this error.     Also, I tried it without the Adam class, and even created an entirely new project, but it still gave me this error.     .The auto complete wont even display the "Process" class

Comment: @Ryios it is compile time error - should not matter what process is starting...

Comment: Random guess - you are not creating desktop/console application somehow. Maybe Phone project?

Comment: My IDE is Xamarin Studio. Could it posibly the .NET assebly

Comment: @Alexei It is a console desktop application

Comment: @JackBarn I've updated your post to explicitly mention Xamarin - feel free to revert/improve if it does not match your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After web searching and attempts, I found the problem.

To fix this, I manually add a reference to `System` in my project options instead of just typing `using System;`. I also need to keep `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top. It's all in the picture below

[image]

Thanks guys for trying to help

Comment: Ah, missing the dll reference for system.  Also you don't have to put using up there if you use the Long syntax "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(..." you just do that when you want everything in those name spaces to be available in the current namespace without having to use full namespace syntax.