# Wait For Process Start C#

Tags: c#, dll-injection

Hey guys I can't seem to get my code to work the way I want it.
I am waiting for a process to start, AKA show up in my Task Manager.
While the process is not found, I keep looping; if process is found then break while loop and perform logic below AKA inject DLL. I have break points in but my code just keeps looping so its like the process is never found although it is showing in task manager.

```
public static int inject(string dllPath, Process tProcess)
{
  Process targetProcess = tProcess;
  string dllName = dllPath;
  const string PROCESSNAME = "BatteryLife.exe";
  // Length == 0 = False?
   while (Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESSNAME).Length == 0)
   {
     var test3 = "";
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     // Length == 1 = True?
     if (Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESSNAME).Length == 1)
      break;
     var test = "";
   }
   var test2 = "";
   // the target process
   // geting the handle of the process - with required privileges
   IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD |   PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, targetProcess.Id);
  // searching for the address of LoadLibraryA and storing it in a pointer
  IntPtr loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
  // name of the dll we want to inject
  // alocating some memory on the target process - enough to store the name of the dll
  // and storing its address in a pointer
  IntPtr allocMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
  // writing the name of the dll there
  UIntPtr bytesWritten;
  WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress,    Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllName), (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) *  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), out bytesWritten);
 // creating a thread that will call LoadLibraryA with allocMemAddress as argument
  CreateRemoteThread(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddr, allocMemAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the PROCESSNAME actually "BatteryLife.exe" and not just "BatteryLife"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know if a process is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `.exe` from the process name `string`.

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BatteryLife");
if (pname.Length == 0)
{
  .....
}
```

Comment: Just to add for the OPs enrichment, take a look at the MSDN docs. Though the description is unclear, the examples show calls without the extension, eg `Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx