# Alarm Clock in C#

Tags: c#, clock, alarm

I had an idea to build an alarm clock in c# with the following features

1. Show a to-do list for the day
2. Play a song from a list of songs chosen

Completed features I've already done

1. Show list of to-do's
2. Play a song
3. Show form between a certain time

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
       MyTimer.Interval = (1 * 60 * 1000); // 1 mins
       MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
       MyTimer.Start();
   }

   private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       WakeUpProcess();
   }

   private void WakeUpProcess()
   {
       StreamReader CurrentAgenda = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Max/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/Advanced_AlarmClock/Advanced_AlarmClock/File Resources/Todays Agenda.txt");
       TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(06, 50, 0); //10 o'clock
       TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(07, 00, 0); //12 o'clock
       TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
       System.IO.StreamReader CurrentAgendaRaw = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:/Users/Max/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/Advanced_AlarmClock/Advanced_AlarmClock/File Resources/Todays Agenda.txt");
       string CurrentAgendaTxt = CurrentAgendaRaw.ReadToEnd();

       if ((now > start) && (now < end))
       {
           this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
           Output.Text = ("Good Morning Max" + Environment.NewLine + CurrentAgendaTxt);            
           Process.Start("C:/Users/Max/Downloads/Juice Newton - Angel Of The Morning.mp3");

       }

   }
   ```

However, I need some solutions to problems I'm facing. 
 - Every time the time requirement is met (Between 6:50 and 7:00) a new instance is opened of the song. I only want one instance open. 
 - Also could someone helep me with how I'd get the program to wake up the computer if possible.

Thank you, Maximus

Comment: Just to check if I understood correctly. The only reason why you are checking if "now" is between the end and start is so that when the "Tick" hits between that time you want to execute that code once. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't work out any other way

Comment: Use a library to handle time for you like [Quartz.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz), it makes stuff like alarms 100x easier.

Comment: Lots of other ways to do what you are doing, some probably better, but to answer your question: `MyTimer.Tick -= MyTimer_Tick;` removes the handler.

Comment: Or calculate the interval based on when you want it to activate (target time minus now).  But still remove the handler if you want it to only execute once.

Comment: One more option would be to just do what you need to in this program and schedule the .exe using the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick solution you can keep on a bool if the alarm has been triggered before or not.

```
bool alarmTriggered = false;
private void WakeUpProcess()
{
    StreamReader CurrentAgenda = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Max/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/Advanced_AlarmClock/Advanced_AlarmClock/File Resources/Todays Agenda.txt");
    TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(06, 50, 0); //10 o'clock
    TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(07, 00, 0); //12 o'clock
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    System.IO.StreamReader CurrentAgendaRaw = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:/Users/Max/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/Advanced_AlarmClock/Advanced_AlarmClock/File Resources/Todays Agenda.txt");
    string CurrentAgendaTxt = CurrentAgendaRaw.ReadToEnd();

    if ((now > start) && (now < end) && !alarmTriggered)
    {
        alarmTriggered = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Output.Text = ("Good Morning Max" + Environment.NewLine + CurrentAgendaTxt);            
        Process.Start("C:/Users/Max/Downloads/Juice Newton - Angel Of The Morning.mp3");

        }
    }
    else {
        alarmTriggered = false;
    }

}
```

PS: The libraries proposed in the comment for your question are a better way to go if you want to progress with your application.

PS2: I am assuming you are just trying stuff around and that this app is supposed to be running multiple days, otherwise removing the event listener is the best choice by far.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Process.Start` to play the song, and leaving it there.

You could try using the return value of `Process.Start` to [check if the process is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268394/402022), or even to [kill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it.

Besides, you are probably better served if you use a library to play your mp3. then you will have finer control over its play time.

Some options include:

- [WMPLib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx) (for Windows, Microsoft Eula)
- [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) (for Windows, Ms-PL)
- [DirectShow](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) (for Windows, LGPL)
- [irrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) (for Windows, Linux and Mac, free for non-commercial use)
- [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) (for Windows, paid, privative)

Note: there is also OpenAL via OpenTK or Monogame but you probably don't wany any of the 3D stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will see which ones work the best :D