# How to check if a program has exited in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to create a small program which will display a message box if a certain program has been exited.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, program meaning function or an application itself? Also, some code showing you've made an attempt would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running

Comment: See also the roughly 1000 other related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+wait+for+process+to+end.

Answer (score 0):

Ths is really subjective,
In my opinion it depends if 
first: you are the one who started the program.
This means if you use the 
Process Class of .NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

So saying you start a program by process.start();
you can check if it is exited using `HasExited` property or you can subscribe to the `Exited` Event of the process

Second Case is :
If the program you are checking was started externally
you can pretty much recheck it at interval
Check the programs that is running by using the process class of .NET

```
Process.GetProcesses();
```

and recheck if the program is still running

But we really don't know, Please give us more details so we can help.

Thanks