# Handling leanft plugin chrome attachment programmatically

Tags: c#, leanft

Im using visual studio 2017, and I have the leanft installed. The runtime engine is launched when I open the IDE. The 1st question is how can I launched the runtime engine programmatically using c#.

The next question centers around a situation where at runtime when I perform the code to attach the plugin to the chrome browser it sometimes times out doing the attachment. How can I handle this better. Basically my tests gets the chromdriver launches a browser and then at that time it will attempt to attach leanft plugin to the running browser. If it times out once in a blue moon, how can I wait for the browser before trying to attach leanft. See link below

[Integrate leanft into selenium tests](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Quality-and-Testing-Blog/Selenium-and-LeanFT-Easily-integrating-LeanFT-into-your-Selenium/ba-p/246519#.WrgqCXMpAwA)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I launched the runtime engine programmatically using c#

Engine launches when you initialize the SDK:

`HP.LFT.SDK.SDK.Init(new HP.LFT.SDK.SdkConfiguration());`

Make sure that if you do this manually, you also perform an `SDK.Cleanup()` at the end of the execution.

Details [here (Custom Frameworks)](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/CustomFrameworks.htm)

> how can I wait for the browser before trying to attach leanft

- You could try to see if there are any processes in the task list:

  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262291/3233388): `Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");`
- or perform `browser.Attach` for 2 or 3 times until it works (basically handle the Time Out exception)
- Each time you try to do `.Attach`, the SDK will try to attach for 20 seconds (by default) using the provided description, you can extend that like this:

  ```
  HP.LFT.SDK.SDK.Init(new HP.LFT.SDK.SdkConfiguration() {
      ResponseTimeoutSeconds = 60
  });
  ```

  If you're not initializing manually, you'll find this setting in `App.config` file that comes when you create a LeanFT test using a provided template.