# How can I make a program execute an action only when a certain process is open?

Tags: c#

I need help finding a way to make my program do an action only when a certain other program is running.

I have tried a `while` loop

```
While process.getprocessbyname("process name").Length != 0
{
     //what i want to execute
}
```

I want my program to run an action only once when a certain process is running. This question is not about finding how I can know if a process is running because I already know how to do so but in fact I am trying to execute a action when a process is running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running

Comment: Add timer, that checks if there's process by name. If yes - do something, if not - do nothing.

Comment: i know how to check if a proccess is running

Comment: lemme try the timer

Comment: `while (Process.GetProcessesByName("processName").Length == 0);` will pause your program until the process is running. Then you can do `//what I want to execute` on the next line. But using a timer is probably better if your program should be doing other things while you wait.

Comment: but will it constantly do ```//what i want to execute``` alot of times if the process is open?

Comment: No, the semi-colon at the end of the `while` statement means that it will just churn on that line until the condition is `false` (which is when the process is running). Then the next line of code will run (one time).

Comment: Please put that as a answer so i can upvote

Comment: You're welcome to answer it yourself if you want, since I don't really like that one-liner and don't have time to write a proper answer right now. :)

Comment: Even without needing your program to process while waiting, it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to put a `Thread.Sleep(100)` as the `while` body so your program doesn't tie up the PC scanning for the process to be running.