# How to detect if a certain process is running?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms application. I need an *if* statement that if a specific procces is running, the label on my form would change color and text. Can I build an *if* statement that will allow me to do that?

I've been trying

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta").Length != 0)
```

but it would not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know if a process is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
{
    // Is running
}
```

Comment: ok thanks but I figured it out I just put the else varible andit workes