# How can I save in a log whenever I open a certain program using Windows Services?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I'm struggling with a problem at my work. I want to develop a little script that runs in background (that's why I'm working with Windows Services) that catches when the user open certain apps, checks if there are available licenses for this program and writes what happened (given license, not given, already given...) in a log on a common server.

My problem comes at the moment that all this programs (or a set of them) share their process name (program.exe for example), so I can't difference between them and so can't compare if there are enough licences.

Any clue or idea?

Edit: My idea is to make every shorcut a .bat file which asks for license, triggers the service and then runs the program. Once the program is opened, I would like to check periodically if its still opened with something like this: [How can I know if a process is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running)

Comment: Can you please share an example of your code, so that we can see what steps you've taken to try solve the problem?

Comment: For now I have not been able to address the problem. My idea is to make every shorcut a .bat file which asks for license, triggers the service and then runs the program. Once the program is opened, I would like to check periodically if its still opened with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262280/how-can-i-know-if-a-process-is-running

Comment: Is that a 3rd party program or do you author it?

Comment: 3rd party, some Autodesk pack programs